# OpenFile always open with PDF

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi boys and girls(of course)

I have this method to open a file

```
public static void openFile(String filePath, Activity activity) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("file://"+filePath));
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error abriendo."+filePath+" Abrir manualmente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

but when I sets the file path to a image.jpg saved in my sdcard it's always try to open with PDF-Drive and it's makes an error try open this kind of file.
but when I open the file directly from a filemanager it's opens with a default imageViewer.
 What I'm doing wrong?
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to compile in java (NetBeans) a lib.jar but when I imported it to the android project it said that I could not find the Path class and the other that gave me error

I solved by creating my own getMimeType

At https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/ I found a fairly complete list
I made a

```
HashMap<String, String> ~ <ext,mime>
```

And to get the mime to the hash that contains all I ask me of the value of the extension

```
map.get(".bmp");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're currently not providing a mime type with the file, so it's likely opening with whatever your system default has been set to.  Have you tried to use [Intent.setDataAndType(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setDataAndType(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String)), and used image/* as the mime type?

Comment: But this will not always be an image